# Calculate difference between two rows, averaged by day

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of `items`, which have a status and creation day

```
+----+-----------+------------+
| id | status    | created    |
+----+-----------+------------+
| 1  | PROCESSED | 2018-12-01 |
+----+-----------+------------+
| 2  | PROCESSED | 2018-12-01 |
+----+-----------+------------+
| 3  | ABORTED   | 2018-12-01 |
+----+-----------+------------+
```

There is a corresponding `item status` table, which is updated when the status changes

```
+----+---------+-----------+------------------+
| id | item_id | status    | created          |
+----+---------+-----------+------------------+
| 1  | 1       | RECEIVED  | 2018-12-01 10:00 |
+----+---------+-----------+------------------+
| 2  | 1       | PROCESSED | 2018-12-01 12:00 |
+----+---------+-----------+------------------+
| 3  | 2       | RECEIVED  | 2018-12-01 11:00 |
+----+---------+-----------+------------------+
| 4  | 2       | PROCESSED | 2018-12-01 12:00 |
+----+---------+-----------+------------------+
| 5  | 3       | RECEIVED  | 2018-12-01 13:00 |
+----+---------+-----------+------------------+
| 6  | 3       | ABORTED   | 2018-12-01 13:30 |
+----+---------+-----------+------------------+
```

I want to produce a report which shows the average time for an item to be processed, grouped by day, excluding items which have been aborted. (the time for an item to be processed is the time difference between `RECEIVED` and `PROCESSED`)

Something like this (duration in seconds):

```
+------------+------------------+
| day        | avg_duration     |
+------------+------------------+
| 2018-12-01 | 5400             |
+------------+------------------+
```

From other questions, I've identified that this can likely be solved using table partitioning, but haven't been able to write a working query. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to show in the report the average of time between the RECEIVED and the PROCESSED time for every item, day by day?

Comment: @Ass3mbler yeah exactly

Comment: can there be more than one `received` and `processed` combination per item_id in a day? if so, how should it be handled?

Comment: No, there will only be one `received`/`processed` row per item, however there could be other statuses between `received` and `processed`, but the calculation should only be the difference between those two

Comment: It's possible that process starts in `2018-12-01` and ends in `2018-12-02`  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the boolean aggregate `bool_and()` to filter out aborted items:

```
select date, avg(duration)
from (
    select created::date as date, item_id, extract(epoch from max(created)- min(created)) as duration
    from item_status
    group by created::date, item_id
    having bool_and(status <> 'ABORTED')
    ) s
group by date

    date    | avg  
------------+------
 2018-12-01 | 5400
(1 row)
```

Comment: . . Amusing.  I would have use `count(*) filter (where status = 'ABORTED') = 0`.  Your way is better, just not what I would have first thought of.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - boolean aggregate is one of those little things for which some people love Postgres.

Answer (score 1):

This requires 2 levels of aggregation, once on item and date and then on date.

```
select dt_created,avg(diff) as avg_diff
from (select item_id
            ,created::date as dt_created
            ,max(case when status = 'PROCESSED' then created end) - max(case when status = 'RECEIVED' then created end) as diff 
      from item_statuses 
      group by item_id,created::date
      having count(case when status = 'ABORTED' then 1 end) = 0
    ) t
group by dt_Created
```